# how can i find which attribute value only contain one type of value?

Tags: sql, oracle

My question may not be clear, but basically I have a table with zip codes, and I need to find the zip codes where all my records indicate there are only commercial entities.

table

```
ID  zip   entity
1   1111   F
2   1111   R
3   1111   C
4   1112   C
5   1112   C
6   1112   C
7   1113   Z
8   1113   S
9   1113   X
```

Return value

```
1112
```

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT(DISTINCT)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the zip codes that only have `entity` 'C'. An easy way to check this is to look at the minimum and maximum value for `entity`; both must be 'C'.

```
select zip
from mytable
group by zip
having min(entity) = 'C' and max(entity) = 'C';
```

Comment: Maybe some would find it easier to see the query's intention with `having sum(case when entity = 'C' then 0 else 1 end) = 0` or `having count(case when entity <> 'C' then 1 end) = 0`instead. There are many ways to achieve the same. The solutions treat nulls differently, but I assume `entity` cannot be null in the table anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of cute ways to get what you want have been presented. Personally, I like sticking with straightforward approaches unless performance demands otherwise. This seems like the clearest to me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.zip
FROM MyTable T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable T2 WHERE T2.zip = T1.zip AND T2.entity <> 'C')
```

The advantage of this, IMO, is that it's clear from looking at the code what it is trying to do, so when you look at the code again in six months you're not left scratching your head.

Comment: Funny, as for such tasks aggregation is the first thing to come to mind, for me your query is more complicated and thus less readable. You need a `DISTINCT`, too. Optimally you'd replace `FROM MyTable T1` by `FROM (select distinct zip from MyTable) T1` which lessens readability further.

Comment: True. People's minds work in different ways, so what seems obvious or "normal" to some, might not seem the same for others and vice versa. Thanks for pointing out the `DISTINCT` issue. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

**Select all commercial zip codes minus non commerical zip codes**

For the diversity of solution purposes, I submit this solution.

The minus operator removes any zip codes which have both commercial and non-commerical entities.

```
SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      zip
  3  FROM
  4      tbl
  5  WHERE
  6      entity = 'C'
  7  GROUP BY
  8      zip
  9  MINUS
 10  SELECT
 11      zip
 12  FROM
 13      tbl
 14  WHERE
 15      entity != 'C'
 16  GROUP BY
 17      zip;
ZIP    
1112
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, this maybe an alternative ( `p^q'` logic ):

```
 select zip
   from mytable
  group by zip
 having sign(sum( decode(entity,'C',1,0) ) ) * ( 1 - sign(sum( decode(entity,'C',0,1) ) )) = 1;
```

[D E M O 1](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4c67cf8e92ce6ed99a943cd6cec804b9)

[D E M O 2 ( go&press execute )](http://tpcg.io/tOaCly)

Comment: Gosh, that looks complicated. `sign(sum(decode(...,1,0))` is simply `max(decode(...,1,0))`. And why calculate a product instead of simply checking the two values? That looks like you are trying to obfuscate your query's intention. What you are showing is merely: `having max(decode(entity,'C',1,0)) = 1 and max(decode(entity,'C',0,1)) = 0`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks, your suggestion seems clearer.